# About Cluster Instance

Tags: sql, sql-server, cluster-computing

I am new to sql server. We are in the process of upgrading sql 2008 to sql 2014 and I was told that our UAT and Prod SQL servers should moved to a cluster instead of upgrading OS/SQL Server.
Can you please explain me in simple word what does it means?

Answer (score 0):

Your situation is contradicting with both scenarios, upgrading the sql 2008 to 2014 and instead moving to cluster, there should be specific reason why someone suggesting to move to cluster rather than upgrading the version.

In Clustering individual servers will work together to provide high availability for database hosted for application. There are few types clustering setup are available that are based on requirement and budget.

You can read more about clustering for SQL server [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh270278(v=sql.120).aspx)